# Why does Kant think we cannot perceive reality?

Tags: kant, perception

Direct realism says that we perceive worldly objects. Kant's view seems to say we do not perceive worldly objects. What we perceive are appearances, not the things themselves. What are his reasons for thinking this and what are the most common objections to his view?

Comment: Give this a perusal:  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-transcendental-idealism/#EmpiThinItse.  Maybe this as well: https://www.con-textoskantianos.net/index.php/revista/article/view/310/457, which argues for the triad of object-appearance and [mental] representation.

Answer (score 4):

Note that Kant distinguishes " phenomena" from pure appearences: phenomena are ( empirically ) real; they are " given" to us.

Many reasons :

(1) only a being endowed with a creating power can know things in themselves; our knowledge is finite, we have to receive things to know them; hence we know them " from the outside" ; our intuition is a reception ( not a creation) --> CPR, Aesthetics

(2) we cannot know things except through space and time that are not properties of things in themselves , but receptivity conditions inherent to human sensibility; --> CPR, Aesthetics

(3) effectiveness ( reality in an informal sense) is itself a category of human mind; things in themselves are not " effective" ( real) --> CPureR, Analytic

(4) admitting that things in space are things in themselves leads to antinomies ( cosmological sophisms ) ; idealism is the only way to escape these antinomies --> CPureR, Dialectics

(5) distinguishing the realm of phenomena and the realm of noumena makes possible to claim that the human subject is both determined ( as a phenomenon belonging to nature) and free , hence capable of morality ( inasmuch as he is endowed with a will, an intellectual appetite) ; this makes sense of moral law --> CPure Reason, Dialectics ; Groundwork Of. Met. Of Morals

I think points ( 4) and (5) are Kant's main motivations for adopting transcendental idealism: saving reason from antinomies ; saving freedom and morality